# Using phpseclib in model laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel, phpseclib

I'm trying to include Crypt/RSA.php in my model, but this always appear "AppClass 'App\Crypt_RSA' not found". Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error appears because you're trying to instantiate a the `Crypt_RSA` class in the `App` namespace where it doesn't exist, because the `Crypt_RSA` class is defined in the global namespace. So you can do one of two things:

**1.** Write a `use` statement at the top of your file:

```
use Crypt_RSA;
```

**2.** Prepend a backslash to the class name when using it:

```
new \Crypt_RSA();
```

You can read more on how namespaces work in the [PHP Namespaces Documentation](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.namespaces.basics.php).